# Deploy grails 2.3.4 to heroku - Error loading DataSource.groovy

Tags: grails, heroku, grails-2.3

I want to deploy my grails app to heroku.

I have created a stack and am now at the stage where I want to push it: `git push heroku master`

However, I receive that:

```
       Done precompiling AST Transformations!
       | Compiling 3 source files
       | Compiling 3 source files.
       | Compiling 3 source files..
       | Compiling 3 source files...
       | Compiling 3 source files....
       | Compiling 3 source files.....
-----> Executing ./grailsw -plain-output -Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=/app/tmp/cac
he war --non-interactive
       |Loading Grails 2.3.4
       |Configuring classpath
       .
       |Environment set to production
       .................................
       |Packaging Grails application
       Precompiling AST Transformations ...
       src /tmp/build_f6c7df12-acc1-407e-84b0-95928c52c3ff/target/work/plugins/p
ostgresql-extensions-0.6.1 /tmp/build_f6c7df12-acc1-407e-84b0-95928c52c3ff/targe
t/classes
       Done precompiling AST Transformations!
       ..
       |Compiling 3 source files
       ..................Error
       |
       Error packaging application: Error loading DataSource.groovy: 1 (Use --st
acktrace to see the full trace)
 !     Failed to build app

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Grails app

To git@heroku.com:quiet-coast-2715.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:quiet-coast-2715.git'
```

I thought that my datasource is broken, so I thats my `DataSource.groovy`:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    username = "admin"
    password = "******"
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    //    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
}

// environment specific settings
environments {

//...

    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

            uri = new URI(System.env.DATABASE_URL?:"postgres://myHerokuUsername:myPassoword@5432/TestDB")

            url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+uri.host+uri.path
            username = uri.userInfo.split(":")[0]
            password = uri.userInfo.split(":")[1]
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I have also added to my `BuildConfig.groovy`:

`runtime postgresql:postgresql:8.4-702.jdbc3'`

I do not see what I have done wrong in my datasource?

I appreciate your answer!

PS.: Any recommendations how to get the full stacktrace in git?

Comment: What is your `myHerokuUsername` in the `uri`?

Comment: I just followed this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-grails#set-up-the-database

Comment: I have tried with your mentioned tutorial and it is working for me with `postgres://myHerokuUsername:myPassoword@5432/TestDB`. I have not change anything in this i.e, not replace myHerokuUsername and myPassword. When I enter my email address in place of `myHerokuUsername` then it given me `null` in `host`. That`s why I want to know what you have in place of `myHerokuUsername`?

Comment: Thx. I have just used my heroku email address as username and my login passoword. For the Port I have used: 5432 and the db name is the same as in `DataSource.groovy`...

Answer (score 2):

The [URI Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) take `[user-info@]host[:port]` syntax and you are providing your email address which itself have a `@` symbol that's why `uri.host` and `uri.userInfo` is null and your build fails.

Try to print `uri.host` and `uri.userInfo` and you can see these are null.
Add following code in your data source

```
dataSource {
  ...
  uri = new URI(System.env.DATABASE_URL ?: "postgres://test@gmail.com:pass@5432/TestDB")
  println "---1---${uri}---${uri.host}---${uri.path}---${uri.userInfo}---"
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + uri.host + uri.path
  ...
}
```

**To resolve the issue just take any string that does not contain `@` symbol for your username and password.** I have taken `test` as username and `pass` as password. like:

```
uri = new URI(System.env.DATABASE_URL ?: "postgres://test:pass@5432/TestDB")
```

and it works.